# Facebook app inside iFrame Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL from frame with URL only on Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, iframe

I'm using jQuery Webcam Plugin, when I try to append the , when my app is inside an iFrame it gives me this error and chrome is the only one who throws it. If access my app  through apps.facebook.com everything works fine.

The flash object on the whole appears to work as expected and it gets appended, but if you attempt to accept and deny buttons do not respond to mouse input nor keyboard input as I tried to select the buttons using the TAB key and then press SPACEBAR but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hitting with my head on the wall I tried something stupid, or maybe something really obvious, the only way to solve this is to add the embed object, in this case was the webcam flash plugin, after an action made by the user. So I had to create a button who is responsible to add the webcam flash object, something like "Turn on your webcam". I hope this answer help, basically you can't add object onload, or already embed in DOM, you must add after a user action, usually a click.